# Browser support of width and height properties of getBoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, getboundingclientrect

I just discovered and really like `getBoundingClientRect` because it includes sub-pixel precision. This has allowed me to create consistent alignment, even if the user types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

It has properties `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, & `width` & `height`.

It is simple to find the browser support on the internet, but not so much for the the `width` and `height` properties in particular. It appears that this was added after the fact. It works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10, but what about IE8 & IE9? I can't test these conveniently.

Comment: Can you use the developer stuff in IE10 to put it in IE8 mode?  (I'm not sure IE10 can do that, but IE9 in IE8 mode would probably get something like that right.)

Comment: Also is `width` different from `right - left`?

Comment: *"use the developer stuff"* Historically the F12 tools in IE have been able to accurately reflect older HTML and CSS parsers, but I have noticed it doesn't work accurately on the old JavaScript interpreters.

Comment: *"is `width` different from `right-left`"* No, based on my limited testing. I still like using `width` because it is shorter and simpler than `right-left`.

Comment: i doubt width and height made it in, unless IE was breaking the rules first and everyone copied, like .innerText for example...

Comment: @dandavis, It works in the latest Firefox, Chrome, and IE10.

Comment: see this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In IE9 as IE8:

```
document.body.getBoundingClientRect() 
[object] {
    right : 2556,
    top : 0,
    bottom : 1195,
    left : 0
}
```

In IE9 as IE9:

```
document.body.getBoundingClientRect() 
[object ClientRect] {
    bottom : 1435,
    height : 1435,
    left : 0,
    right : 2544,
    top : 0,
    width : 2544
}
```

So, I'd say yes on IE9, no on IE8...

Comment: IE 7 also does not support width and height. Thanks Microsoft for the janky programming experience!

Comment: We discovered that right-left in IE8 is performed as integer math, whereas width in IE9 can be floating point.  Half a pixel can be considerable if you are trying to line up two elements on a page.